# Diagram with loops in tikzcd

Tags: equations, diagrams, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I would like to know how we can draw this diagram in **tikzcd**

[image]

Those are not dotted arrows but simple ones.

You can add how we can draw an isolated point with an arrow to itself.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \bullet\ar[r]\ar[d]\ar[rd]\ar[loop, <->, in=170,out=100,looseness=5]&[10pt] \bullet\ar[d]\ar[loop, <->, in=10,out=80,looseness=5] \\
    \bullet\ar[r]\ar[loop, <->, in=190,out=-100,looseness=5]& \bullet\ar[loop, <->, in=-80,out=-10,looseness=5] 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]